# sequelize UniqueConstraintError not showing msg with Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an express application using sequelize ORM and want to send a custom message when this error happens with an unique field. The problem is that when checking the error object that is thrown, it doesn't give me any kind of useful data that i can use for creating a message to send to the client. I tried to test this with a simple User model to log the error. Here is the user init method:

```
User.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: {
        name: 'email',
        msg: 'This is a custom message'
      },
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
```

And this is my app entry point:

```
const db = require('./models/index');
const User = db.User;

(async () => {
    try {
        await db.sequelize.sync({ force: true });
        await User.create({
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'
        });
        await User.create({
            firstName: 'Jane',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // log the see what's inside the error object
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

When i run the app, i'm logging the error:

```
original: error: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «Users_email_key»
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Facultad\Proyectos\Sequelize Test\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Facultad\Proyectos\Sequelize Test\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Facultad\Proyectos\Sequelize Test\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Facultad\Proyectos\Sequelize Test\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
      at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
    length: 213,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23505',
    detail: 'Ya existe la llave (email)=(johnsmith@gmail.com).',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'Users',
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: 'Users_email_key',
    file: 'nbtinsert.c',
    line: '670',
    routine: '_bt_check_unique',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","firstName","lastName","email","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","firstName","lastName","email","createdAt","updatedAt";',
    parameters: [
      'Jane',
      'Doe',
      'johnsmith@gmail.com',
      '2021-12-31 22:49:00.903 +00:00',
      '2021-12-31 22:49:00.903 +00:00'
    ]
  },
  fields: {},
  sql: 'INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","firstName","lastName","email","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","firstName","lastName","email","createdAt","updatedAt";'
}
```

The thing is, non of this gives me valuable data about what failed, for example if more than one field is unique. Also, the errors array and the fields object are empty, which according to the docs maybe that would tell which field is the one that the database is checking. I tried this with a sqlite database and the error was way more intuitive. I understand that according to the database one is using the dialect will change, but in this case it isn't even taking in account the "msg" option assigned in the model definition.

After explaining all of this, my question would be: is this behaviour normal with postgres, or am i missing something?

Im using node v14.18, sequelize ORM v6.12.4, postgresql 14.1 on Windows 10

Comment: It told you what tripped the error: `constraint: 'Users_email_key',`  and why: `detail: 'Ya existe la llave (email)=(johnsmith@gmail.com).',`. Not sure what more you need?